# Get the File Name if have on Root and Sub Root Folders In Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph

i want to Access OneDrive Folders Images Files in Access Thorugh Microsoft Graph but Proble is i Get the Data From Perticular Folder wise but i want to get Image File Name Directly no need to put Perticular Folder name. want to Get files if is in Any folders which is on Root.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/itemimages/Category1/?$expand=children($select=id,name,weburl)

````
```$expand=children($select=id,name,weburl)
````

Comment: Try it out GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{path-relative-to-root}:/children` you could refer [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-id)

Comment: May I add this comment as answer?